# Remove elements with named child element

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML where I remove tags using this code:

```
XElement xmlElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
xmlElement.XPathSelectElement("//"+ tagToRemove).Remove();
```

But now I have another problem. On the method above I remove a specific tag but now I want to remove the tag below. In the XML there is a lot of tag called               `param` so I can't just remove that.

What I was thinking about was to remove the tag where the subtag 
`name = ERP_OUTPUT_400_20_DOCUMENTATIONLANGUAGE_field`

```
<param type=\"read-only\" committed=\"no\" changed=\"no\" visible=\"yes\" no=\"1\">
    <name>ERP_OUTPUT_400_20_DOCUMENTATIONLANGUAGE_field</name>
    <desc>ERP OUTPUT 400 20 DOCUMENTATIONLANGUAGE</desc>
    <val>SV;</val>
    <val-desc>SV;</val-desc>
    <domain name=\"function\" />
    <aux>
        <prop name=\"hidden\">no</prop>
    </aux>
</param>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select element having child element `<name>` value equals specific name, you can use the following XPath query :

```
//element_name[name='specific_name']
```

Example based on your existing code :

```
var name = "ERP_OUTPUT_400_20_DOCUMENTATIONLANGUAGE_field";
var xpath = String.Format("//{0}[name='{1}']", tagToRemove, name);
xmlElement.XPathSelectElement(xpath).Remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there some way to make a method where i don't have to add the parent tag? Delete any parent tag that has a child with name

Comment: @DanielGustafsson simply change the parent name with star (`*`) : `//*[name='specific_name']`